# Which is the best way to maintain the two table values?

Tags: symfony

I have two tables such as

```
User
ID  name   count
1   cat    2
2   dog    1
3   rabbit 1
4   tiger  0


Lesson
ID  time   student
1   09:00  1(cat)
2   10:00  1(cat)
3   13:00  2(dog)
4   15:00  3(rabbit)
```

User.count means how many times each user appear in Lesson table.
I want to keep this number correctly.

Method A)

You can increment User.count by PHP each time that you add row to Lesson 
  but you have to write cords both when you add a row to Lesson or delete a row from Lesson

Method B)

Using PrePersist or PreUpdate ( I am using doctrine 2)
But is it possible to access User table when PreUpdate of Lesson entity is triggered?

Method C)

You can connect some mysql native method ?

Which way is the best way to maintain these value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You cannot acces other tables/entities in prePersist/postPersist etc. functions.
- You should not use native database access functions.

You should create a more service oriented application. I assume you add a new lesson by doing the following in your controllers :

```
$doctrine->getManager->persist($newLesson);
```

Instead of doing that, you should create a service that will do the insertion and the update of the count for you. Something like a `LessonService` having the following method :

```
public function addLesson($lessonModel) {
    // Add the lesson to the database

    // Increment the counter here

}
```

Comment: Thanks ,I will do this way.